# Gitlab push without password

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, documentation

***Edit***
Basic protocol now found from some notes. But Seir has already answered so I probably can't delete this. Her/his answer may be useful to someone though.

---

I use **GitLab**, not Github. This question is specific to the former.

I push to and pull from projects using both W10 and Linux (Mint 20).

I really know next to nothing about communicating with the GitLab server, or what SSH keys are and how they work (I have read about them but still don't understand). I've found virtually no documentation at GitLab explaining what I should be doing.

In W10: I can push without ever being asked for username + password. This applies even when I have just created a new project. It is lost in the mists of time how I set this up... and I don't know how to find out. I have a suspicion this might be "HTTPS" access.

In Linux: when I push I always have to enter username + password. I don't know whether things can be set up so I never have to enter username + password, or whether I have to do this on a per-project basis. **One** of my projects never asks for username + password. The last time I tried setting things up was about 2 years ago. Maybe I succeeded with this one project.

Can someone explain what I have to do or point me to a source of information for my very low level of understanding?

Comment: You do not *have to* use ssh, but ssh is my preference as it's far less complicated than https and the bazillion authentication helpers that use of https brings with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitlab%5D+%5Bssh-keys%5D+create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup an SSH key for each individual system.
I suspect you've already added an SSH key for your W10 system.

Navigate to your user settings → SSH Keys

[image]

Now click on the link 'generate one' and follow the instructions.

GitLab Docs: [Use SSH keys to communicate with GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I've found some notes from January this year which explains the basic protocol ... on that page I find an already existing SSH key. Now you've answered I probably can't delete my question. Maybe your answer will be useful to someone else though!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as I can't delete this because Seir has given a useful answer, I might as well give the notes I made, not least because the page linked to at GitLab in Seir's answer is a bit complicated.

This is for a Linux context:

- first you have to create an SSH key ... the details are as follows:
- in Terminal do `$ ls ~/.ssh`: if you have a file named id_rsa.pub or id_dsa.pub you already have a key
- otherwise:
- `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "Comment for key"`
- name: press Enter
- passphrase (i.e. password)
- then go to Gitlab site ... personal icon top right --> Edit profile --> in account page... "SSH Keys" in left column
- on the local machine, do this : `$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and copy the entire contents
- in the box under Add an SSH key / Key, paste the contents.
- give a simple explanatory title in "Title". Set "Expiration date" to 31/12/2199
- click "Add key"
- on the local machine do this, probably in the directory where your .git file or directory is located:

  `$ git remote set-url origin ssh://git@gitlab.com/[my-gitlab-account-name]/[my-project-name]`